# Can't find Tomcat Runtime in Eclipse Mars

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, server, eclipse-mars

I am new to web programming in Java and I am struggling with some problems. I want to create a new runtime server using Tomcat, but the only things that I can select from Apache folder are Geronimo related. I have installed all the adapters for Apache, I really don't know what else I can do. 
Please help me.

[image]

Answer (score 9):

I had to add the JST Server Adapters and JST Server Adapter Extensions as well. Go through Help -> Install New Software to get them. Then when I went to the New Server Runtime Environment (your screen cap) I had a second Apache option and in that were the Tomcat servers.

Comment: Worked for me as well. Also used http://crunchify.com/error-starting-apache-tomcat-server-the-jre-could-not-be-found-edit-the-server-and-change-the-jre-location/ to solve my problem once JSTs were downloaded.

Answer (score 1):

Is it missing just from the menu maybe?

If you goto "Window > Show View > Other..." and then type Servers in the filter, does it show up?

Also make sure you downloaded the "Eclipse For Java EE Developers" package as I do not believe the "Eclipse for Java Developers" contains the Servers view.

Eclipse for Java EE Developers: http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/indigosr1

Answer (score 0):

The apache tomcat plugin for eclipse is part of the [WTP (Eclipse Web Tools Platform)](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/), but you can get it separately from [here](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/eclipse-tomcat-plugin). Just drag the link to your workspace and install it. You will then be able to configure a running Tomcat Server in your eclipse IDE.

If you run into problems with the Tomcat plugin then the next step I'd follow is just to install the WTP [here](http://download.eclipse.org/releases/mars). Copy the link and paste it into the intallation url field. Check the whole WTP option and install everything.

Comment: That is rather strange... Try installing the whole WTP then. You'de be better off with the eclipse for java ee developers edition. I'm just trying to see if there is a solution to keep your current configuration. You did try this page right?: https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/eclipse-tomcat-plugin.

Comment: I installed the Tomcat plugin and  I can run a tomcat server from the new tab, but still it doesn't appear in my new server runtime window and I can not link a new project to this (as a targe routine )

Comment: It might have to do with something in the WTP that needs to be there. It's good that at least you can run it now. I think what's missing is some links between Tomcat and Eclipse and that's something that only WTP provides, so I'd say try that and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the same problem as you, and I'm using eclipse oxygen.

Then I try eclipse luna, wow, it works!